# How to replace a regexp group with a post proceed value?

Tags: java, regex

I have this code to

```
public static String ProcessTemplateInput(String input, int count) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([^\\}]+)\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String newelem=SelectRandomFromTemplate(matcher.group(1), count);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Input is:

```
 String s1 = "planets {Sun|Mercury|Venus|Earth|Mars|Jupiter|Saturn|Uranus|Neptune}{?|!|.} Is this ok? ";
```

Output example:

```
String s2="planets Sun, Mercury. Is this ok? ";
```

I would like to replace the {} set of templates with the picked value returned by the method. How do I do that in Java1.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `appendReplacement`/`appendTail`:

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(output, SelectRandomFromTemplate(matcher.group(1), count)); 
}
matcher.appendTail(output);
return output.toString();
```

Comment: Java 7 will finally allow the use of StringBuilder for this.